# System.Threading.Timer callback to main thread

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

This is my scenario: I'm doing communication between devices on a wireless network. When two devices are communicating but their connection drops unexpectedly, messages are automatically buffered until they are able to connect to each other again. This means I need to periodically (every X seconds) update a list of everyone who is available on the current network (since it's many devices connecting to many others). When some client is discovered who may have been forcefully disconnected earlier, this means some messages may be buffered for this client.

Refreshing the list of devices on the network every X seconds seems like a job for [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). The thing is that I'm worried about data race conditions when this timer thread will try to send messages, but the main thread might try to send the remaining messages too (for a different reason).

So I'm wondering - can I raise an event on the main thread from within the `System.Threading.Timer` thread? Or how would I approach this otherwise, considering any method needs to work on both Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 (Store apps).

Comment: You can, you have to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke().  Whether that's useful is questionable, it doesn't become any "better" than a regular DispatcherTimer unless you have substantial code to run in the callback *before* you invoke.  Such code *will* be dangerous if it touches any variables that the UI thread uses as well, locking is a hard requirement if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke:

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Place delegate on the Dispatcher. 
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new TimerDispatcherDelegate(TimerWorkItem));
}
```

Or, as @HansPassant suggested, consider using `DispatcherTimer`.